# Assign char literal in "if" block

Tags: c++, memory

I am now confused about this code.

```
int flag = 1;
struct {
    char * data;
}
neco;
if(flag) {
    neco.data = "index.html";
}
// insert code here...
std::cout << neco.data;
}
```

Is secure to print neco.data after "if" block, or memory allocated inside if block is "cleaned" after "if" block ends?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"?

Comment: This is not C/C++, it's C++.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar: yes code is c++, but the problem is same for all those languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is secure to print neco.data after "if" block, or memory alocated
>   inside if block is "cleaned" after "if" block ends?

String literals never go out of scope. The program itself is their scope.

As us2012 mentioned in the comments, **you need to make sure neco.data is initialized** or never use it if that branch wasn't taken.

Comment: +1, but I would add that the code provided by OP is may not be safe as `neco.data` is uninitialized if `flag == 0`. (It currently says `int flag = 1;` but who knows when that might change...

Answer (score 0):

> Is secure to print neco.data after "if" block, or memory alocated inside if block is "cleaned" after "if" block ends?

The string literal in question, `"index.html"`, will continue to exist past the end of the `if` block, so in this respect the code is fine.